# React : Cycle life problem expected / redirect problem

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-router, use-effect, lifecycle

For my first project with React, i tried to use useContext() for call my data mocked.
But after that, i have a problem.

**The problem** :
You go to a housing page, you change the apartment ID in the URL with a Dummy ID and you update it.
Great! The redirection to the 404 is done.
So you go back to the home page by clicking on the link of the 404.
You go back to any housing page => the 404 is always present.
You repeat, you then return to the home page and you click again on a housing card and WOW the problem no longer exists.

**My Provider**

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react"
import fetchLocationData from "../../services/localFetch"

export const FetchDataContext = createContext()

export const FetchDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [locationData, setLocationData] = useState({})
  const [locationsData, setLocationsData] = useState([])
  const [allLocationLoading, setAllLocationLoading] = useState(false)
  const [isLocationLoading, setIsLocationLoading] = useState(false)
  const [errorAPI, setErrorAPI] = useState(false)
  const [error404, setError404] = useState(false)

  async function fetchLocationById(locId) {
    try {
      setError404(false)
      const response = await fetchLocationData.getLocById(locId)
      response ? setLocationData(response) : setError404(true)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      setErrorAPI(true)
    } finally {
      setIsLocationLoading(true)
      console.log("in provider :", error404)
    }
  }

  async function fetchAllLocations() {
    try {
      const response = await fetchLocationData.getAll()
      setLocationsData(response)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err)
      setErrorAPI(true)
    } finally {
      setAllLocationLoading(true)
    }
  }

  return (
    <FetchDataContext.Provider
      value={{
        errorAPI,
        error404,
        isLocationLoading,
        allLocationLoading,
        locationData,
        locationsData,
        fetchLocationById,
        fetchAllLocations,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </FetchDataContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

**My router**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <BlocPage>
        <Header />
        <FetchDataProvider>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
            <Route path="/apartment/:locId" element={<ProfileLocation />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
          </Routes>
        </FetchDataProvider>
      </BlocPage>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

**My housing page**

```
function ProfileLocation() {
  const { locId } = useParams()
 
  const {
    errorAPI,
    error404,
    locationData,
    isLocationLoading,
    fetchLocationById,
  } = useContext(FetchDataContext)

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocationById(locId)
  }, [])

  const rating = parseInt(locationData.rating)

  if (errorAPI) {
    return (
      <span>
        Oups une erreur est survenue ... Veuillez recommencer ultérieurement.
      </span>
    )
  }

  if (error404) {
    return <Navigate to="/error404" />
  }
 
  return (
    <div>
      {isLocationLoading ? (
        <>
          <Slider pictures={locationData.pictures} />
          <ResponsiveWrapper>
            <FirstSectionWrapper>
              <Title>{locationData.title}</Title>
              <Geolocation>{locationData.location}</Geolocation>
              <TagsWrapper>
                {locationData.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
                  <Tag key={`${tag}-${index}`} label={tag} />
                ))}
              </TagsWrapper>
            </FirstSectionWrapper>

            <SecondSectionWrapper>
              <OwnerWrapper>
                <HomeOwnerName>{locationData.host.name}</HomeOwnerName>
                <HomeOwerPicture
                  src={locationData.host.picture}
                  alt={locationData.host.name}
                />
              </OwnerWrapper>
              <StarsWrapper>
                <StarScale ratingValue={rating} starType="full" />
                <StarScale ratingValue={rating} starType="empty" />
              </StarsWrapper>
            </SecondSectionWrapper>
          </ResponsiveWrapper>

          <CollapseSectionWrapper>
            <CollapseWrapper>
              <Collapse
                pageType="profil"
                label="Description"
                contentType="paragraph"
                contentText={locationData.description}
              />
            </CollapseWrapper>
            <CollapseWrapper>
              <Collapse
                pageType="profil"
                label="Équipements"
                contentType="list"
                contentText={locationData.equipments}
              />
            </CollapseWrapper>
          </CollapseSectionWrapper>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Loader />
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProfileLocation
```

Maybe it’s an async code problem?

Comment: `error404` is still true when you "navigate" back to `"/apartment/:locId"`. Can you more clearly explain *exactly* how you are getting to/from pages? Browser back/forward buttons? Manual URL manipulation? UI navigation buttons/links the app is rendering? Where is the link to navigate from the 404 UI?

Comment: To trigger error 404, I change the ID manually in the url.
I never activate the back/forward browser buttons.
I use the links in the header (go home).
Yes navigation buttons/links are rendered.

Comment: I suppose you need to clear/reset the `error404` state when you navigate *away* from any page that triggered `error404` true. Can you edit your post to include a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] so we can see the navigation as well? What is the purpose of `fetchLocationById` and the `error404` state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that only navigating forward to a route rendering a component that calls `fetchLocationById` will ever manage to clear/set the `error404` state back to false.

I suggest instead of passing `error404` back to the components that the `FetchDataProvider` handles rendering the error UI upon the error condition. Having it redirect to a specific error page.

Example:

```
<FetchDataProvider>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    <Route path="/apartment/:locId" element={<ProfileLocation />} />
    <Route path="/404" element={<Error404 />} /> // <-- add route
    <Route path="*" element={<Error />} />
  </Routes>
</FetchDataProvider>
```

...

```
const Error404 = () => (
  <div>Oups une erreur est survenue ... Veuillez recommencer ultérieurement.</div>
);
```

...

```
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

export const FetchDataProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  ...

  async function fetchLocationById(locId) {
    try {
      setError404(false)
      const response = await fetchLocationData.getLocById(locId)
      if (response) {
        setLocationData(response);
      } else {
        navigate("/error404", { replace: true });
      }
    } catch (err) {
      navigate("/error404", { replace: true });
    } finally {
      setIsLocationLoading(true);
    }
  }

  ...

  return (
    ...
  );
}
```

...

```
function ProfileLocation() {
  const { locId } = useParams();
 
  const {
    locationData,
    isLocationLoading,
    fetchLocationById,
  } = useContext(FetchDataContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLocationById(locId);
  }, [fetchLocationById, locId]); // <-- don't forget to add proper dependencies

  const rating = parseInt(locationData.rating);

  return (
    <div>
      {isLocationLoading ? (
        <>
          <Slider pictures={locationData.pictures} />
          <ResponsiveWrapper>
            <FirstSectionWrapper>
              <Title>{locationData.title}</Title>
              <Geolocation>{locationData.location}</Geolocation>
              <TagsWrapper>
                {locationData.tags.map((tag, index) => (
                  // eslint-disable-next-line react/no-array-index-key
                  <Tag key={`${tag}-${index}`} label={tag} />
                ))}
              </TagsWrapper>
            </FirstSectionWrapper>

            <SecondSectionWrapper>
              <OwnerWrapper>
                <HomeOwnerName>{locationData.host.name}</HomeOwnerName>
                <HomeOwerPicture
                  src={locationData.host.picture}
                  alt={locationData.host.name}
                />
              </OwnerWrapper>
              <StarsWrapper>
                <StarScale ratingValue={rating} starType="full" />
                <StarScale ratingValue={rating} starType="empty" />
              </StarsWrapper>
            </SecondSectionWrapper>
          </ResponsiveWrapper>

          <CollapseSectionWrapper>
            <CollapseWrapper>
              <Collapse
                pageType="profil"
                label="Description"
                contentType="paragraph"
                contentText={locationData.description}
              />
            </CollapseWrapper>
            <CollapseWrapper>
              <Collapse
                pageType="profil"
                label="Équipements"
                contentType="list"
                contentText={locationData.equipments}
              />
            </CollapseWrapper>
          </CollapseSectionWrapper>
        </>
      ) : (
        <Loader />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```